# Dealing with deep package names in perl and their exported constants and subroutines

Tags: perl

This has probably been asked before, but I'm not sure what to search for. The problem is that I'm dealing with a package that is 4 directories deep and has a rather long name. Within the package are some exported constants that I want to use in main, but I don't want to use their fully qualified names, nor do I want to use their local name (the part after the last ::). For example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Vendor::FirstPackage::SecondPackage::ThirdPackage qw(const_a);

# this is works, but I want to include the last package
my $x = const_a;

# this throws bareword error
my $y = ThirdPackage::const_a;

# this throws undefined subroutine 
my $z = ThirdPackage::const_a();
```

Is there a way to access the constant via it's last package name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use Package::Alias 'ThirdPackage' => 'Vendor::FirstPackage::SecondPackage::ThirdPackage';
```

But I'd recommend just using the fully qualified name.

Comment: Other than style, is there a functional reason for using the FQN instead of an alias?

Comment: @gogators: the alias is in essence creating a global variable %ThirdPackage::.  this is bad for all the usual reasons global variables are bad.  e.g. what happens when there's also a Vendor2::Foo::Bar::ThirdPackage that you also want to alias?

Comment: I actually think bart's answer is a lot better.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a package like this in your main script:

```
package ThirdPackage;
use strict;
use Vendor::FirstPackage::SecondPackage::ThirdPackage qw(const_a);
```

Then you should be able to access `const_a` as `ThirdPackage::const_a`. If you will put that package at the beginning of your main script, then main code should be separated with `package main;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Module::Load](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Load) like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Load qw(load_remote);
BEGIN {
    load_remote 'ThirdPackage', 'Vendor::FirstPackage::SecondPackage::ThirdPackage', qw(const_a);
}

my $x = ThirdPackage::const_a;
```